# empty '$_POST' values from AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When trying to show the results of my $_POST on the php side I am getting 
"array(0){}" when I use:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I have tried the most basic solutions where I've created a new button that executes a new function called "sendAJAX()":

```
<head>
<script>    
function sendAJAX(){
       $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "includes/displayAJAX.php",
           data: { name: "John Doe", age: "19" }
       }).done(function( msg ) {
           alert(msg);
       });
window.top.location = "includes/displayAJAX.php";
}
</script>
</head>

<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
<button onclick="sendAJAX()">POST</button>
</div>
```

on the php file it is simply:

```
<?php
print $_POST["name"];
?>
```

I get the success alert pop up with the expected data but when I redirect to that php page "Undefined index: name" instead of "name:john doe, age:19"

Comment: What do you mean *"When I redirect to that php page"*? If you navigate to the page directly, you wouldn't be POSTing any data, therefore your `$_POST` would be empty.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned I am just learning all of this. I understand now as per Joseph's response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not examine the results of the `$_POST` directly from the PHP page itself.

You have to examine the results as they are sent back to the calling ajax function.

A good way to do this is to use your browser's console.

Your ajax should look like this:

```
function sendAJAX(){
       $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "includes/displayAJAX.php",
           data: { 
             name: "John Doe",
              age: "19" 
            },
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data); //Use your browser's console to see your data here.
           }

       });
    });
```

Your php should look like this:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

If after this you need to redirect to another page you can add the appropriate code inside the ajax's success function.

Like so:

```
success: function(data){
             window.top.location = "path/to/another/page.php";
          }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahhhh, so no way to view on that page?

Comment: Not like you are trying to do.  You will see the response from the `includes/displayAJAX.php` page after if is sent back to your ajax function.  That is the entire point of ajax.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your super quick response! Much appreciated!

Comment: Yup no problem. ~Cheers